# How can I call a cell's contents in MS Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel to display a chart with some chart summary information in a textbox on top of it. The texbox must contain various data which is obtained from several cell formulas. To avoid changing the values of the text box manually everyday, I would like the textbox to be automatically updated by using the necessary cell values which are elsewhere in the Excel sheet.

What I would like to know is: Is there a way to reference the contents of several cells in a textbox?

Will I have to write a macro to do this? Or am I missing the trick altogether?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I'm not very clear on what you're trying to accomplish. Excel automatically updates the chart whenever I update the values. Would you please post a small example of what you'd like to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert text box
2. Click the text box, cut it, click your graph and paste.
3. With the text box selected, click the formula bar and insert your formula referencing the cell you want.  Should be good to go.